# Filtering Core modules from the V8 Stack Trace in Node JS

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

I'm hooking a stack trace from the Error object and returning an array of `callSite` objects and I would like to filter out the Node core and native sites.  Mostly this is not a problem and I can just run a regex match on `path.relative(process.cwd(), t.getFileName())` as most files will have their full path name.  However, some modules have unqualified names, for example `events.js` which is a core module so, this method will fail.

I have a few ideas like...

1. register the file names of the modules I want to target, for example I can gather all of the .js files from the project directories.
2. I noticed that the `events.js` is not in the cache (`require.cache`) so maybe that is the case for all core modules so I could mark them as core if I can't find them in the cache.  This seems a bit heavy though.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying all paths are absolute except the core nodejs ones? Assuming the core modules are all in the same directory (I haven't checked), you could replace `t.getFileName()` with `path.resolve(coreModulesDir, t.getFileName())`, where `coreModulesDir` is the absolute path of the core modules.

Comment: The problem is that the core modules are indistinguishable from files in the project root. But, you gave me an idea: maybe I can use `require.resolve` to get the full path of core modules.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `process.binding` or safer `require('builtin-modules')` since `process.binding` is not public.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path.isAbsolute as the core modules will have a relative path and your files would have an absolute path.